# Configuring a Lightning Component via a Canvas App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, canvas, community-builder

I'm wondering if it is possible to configure a Lightning Component via a Canvas App?

The scenario would be:

1. User drags Lightning Component into a Community Page via the Community Builder.
2. The Lightning Component would initialize with the Canvas App and require to sign into third party web app/canvas app.
3. User signs into and authenticates within Canvas App, do some configuration then save.
4. Lightning Component and Canvas App listens to each other and sets configuration.
5. User publishes community page with configured Lightning Component.

I can't seem to find any documentation about this, but figured I should try and ask anyways. Or if someone has a workaround to recommend, that would be great.

Comment: The above approach will definitely work and there is no documentation to confirm but should work

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I'll check it out and see if I can get the Canvas App running via force:canvasApp in a Lightning Component.