# force:canvasApp in a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, canvas, community-builder

I have a simple Lightning Component with a Canvas App embedded in it via the force:canvasApp tag.

**CanvasTestComponent.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <div class="canvas-container">
        <force:canvasApp developerName="canvasTutorial" namespacePrefix="canvasNameSpace"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

This works perfectly, when I include this in a Lightning App like so:

**CanvasTestApp.app**

```
<aura:application >
    <c:CanvasTestComponent />
</aura:application>
```

However, when I try to drag the component into a section of the Community Builder, it does not work. Nothing actually happens. Upon opening the console, I get this error:

> Failed to load resource:
>   https://some_example_org--livepreview.na3.force.com/sfsites/c/sfsites/c/jslibrary/1471293714000/ui-sfdc-javascript-impl/SfdcCoreLean.js
>   the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Anyone know if I'm missing something? I found this [question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kELjIAM) here, but seems like no one has answered it and it seems pretty recent with Winter 17.

Comment: You might want to open a case here for this .This sounds like a bug ,Did you try embedding in app builder to narrow down the issue ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I did try embedding this in the app builder and it works. It just doesn't work on the community builder. Any other recommendations for debugging before I submit a case?

Comment: No I feel it's a bug in the component .You can work around using vf and iframing vf inside lightning component  .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava thanks. I don't know how I feel about using an iFrame. Although, it seems like Canvas Apps are iFrames to begin with anyways. I was trying to get this to work to see if I can fiddle with my previous question in which you answered http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149612/configuring-a-lightning-component-via-a-canvas-app